# Number.intValue rounds

Tags: java, numbers

I have a Number object and invoke "intValue()" which will return an Integer value.
However if the value is bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE, the method rounds. That's okay, but I want to be informed if the function rounds.

Is there a way to get notified when intValue will round?

As workaround I can do:

```
if (Number.longValue() > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  okay, it will be rounded... some logic here
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you heard of `BigInteger`? Its sole purpose is to deal with numbers beyond the galaxy.

Comment: How would you want to get a 'notification'?

Comment: @Masud: Since he's talking about values bigger than maximum `Integer`, it wouldn't be rounding like with floats. Simply meaning `Long` values that are bigger than any `Integer` could be and thus cannot be described accurately as `Integer`s.

Comment: I think the way you have done it is the way to go. I wouldn't even consider this as a "workaround".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast and catch the exception

```
Integer intVersion;
Number longVersion = 2332212344334L;

try{
    intVersion = (Integer) longVersion;
}
catch(ClassCastException e) {
    System.out.println("here is your notification :)");
}
```

Comment: This would be using exceptions handling for control flow, which is considered bad design.

Comment: Using exceptions is a good design to handle "exceptional" cases - things that you'd rather not have interrupt the normal flow. It is often more efficient than using condition clauses and many usages are considered idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

[Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) itself is abstract class. [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is child class of [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). May be, in your case it's enough to check whether object's instanse is [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) or not?

```
Number num = ....
int i = 0;
if (num instanceof Integer) {
  i = (Integer)num;
}
```

Comment: I think it's not enough since ´Long´ can still have a value that also fits into an ´Integer´.